# PHP Get data from data base in user define order

Tags: php, mysql

I want to give privilege to a user to arrange list of item in his/her define order.
That user can change the sequence of list from interface and update it in to database.

I write code for it and use ascending order logic, but It is  not full fill my requirement i need some technical approach

If some one have better approach and idea to this thing in simpler way then please guide me

what logic should i have to follow

Comment: Dont use mysql_* please read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1):

`Order by` clause should always come after the `where clause`

```
select * from our_team where id = '$id' ORDER BY our_team desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
 <?php   $id = $_GET['id'];
    $row    = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from our_team  where id = '$id' ORDER BY our_team DESC"));
?>
```